# How to change my VBA code to change row color based on change in text or value and not just value?

Tags: text, colors, excel, rows, vba

I am using the following VBA code (provided by Vicky) to change the color of the rows in a spreadsheet each time the value in column A changes. The only problem is, if it runs into something that isn't a value (such as "10000CO") it ends the command, thus no longer changing the row colors, and comes up with an error message. Is there any way to manipulate the code so that it changes the color when the value OR text in column A changes? [Note that I am using Excel 2007]

```
Sub colorize()

Dim r As Long, val As Long, c As Long

r = 4
val = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value
c = 19

For r = 4 To ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value) Then
    Exit For
End If

If ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value <> val Then
    If c = 19 Then
         c = 20
    Else
        c = 19
    End If
End If

ActiveSheet.Rows(r).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .ColorIndex = c
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With

val = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change type of val from Long to String